# SpinBoxDelegate and QItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I work on project It's like SpinBoxDelegate in Qt sample project but I must customize It, I mean having different widget(textbox) in second and third column of table view instead of spainBox.What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead `tableView.setItemDelegate(&delegate);` from the example something like [QTableView::setItemDelegateForColumn()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qabstractitemview.html#itemDelegateForColumn).

Plus have a look at [this](http://qtwiki.org/Creating_QTableView_TextEditDelegate) one tutor.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a QTableWidget instead of a QTableView you can use QTableWidget.setCellWidget() to put another widget inside a cell.  For instance, you could put your own QLineEdit or QSpinBox in the cell.

Unfortunately, if you have to display too many of these it will cause performance issues.